# How to replace multiple blocks with /fill

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to remove all the water from around an ocean monument. Instead of manually scooping it up, i am using the command `/fill`. There are a lot of waterlogged blocks such as kelp and seagrass that i also want to remove.

My command looks like this:
`/fill ~10 ~-1 ~10 ~-10 ~-21 ~10 minecraft:glass replace minecraft:water`

Is there any way to replace multiple blocks at once with `/fill` or `/clone`?

> **I would like to replace these blocks:**

- `tall_seagrass`
- `water`
- `kelp_plant`
- `seagrass`

I am using Minecraft Java Edition snapshot 20W22A.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? what should i change in my question?

Comment: Have you researched how to do your question before posting? Posts are often downvoted because the user thought you didn't do enough research.

Comment: You can also consider improving the title. The title should have similar quality to the question body.

Answer (score 2):

Just run the command multiple times, one for each item.

Run it once with water, once with seagrass, once with tall seagrass, and once with kelp plants.

Comment: i used command blocks and /execute.

Comment: How exactly did you do that? The whole community would benefit from your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

I placed 4 command blocks, each one was `always active` and `repeat`. I then put one of the following commands in each of the command blocks

```
/execute at <user> run fill ~10 ~-1 ~10 ~-10 ~-21 ~10 minecraft:glass replace minecraft:water

/execute at <user> run fill ~10 ~-1 ~10 ~-10 ~-21 ~10 minecraft:glass replace minecraft:tall_seagrass

/execute at <user> run fill ~10 ~-1 ~10 ~-10 ~-21 ~10 minecraft:glass replace minecraft:seagrass

/execute at <user> run fill ~10 ~-1 ~10 ~-10 ~-21 ~10 minecraft:glass replace minecraft:kelp_plant
```